# Applying aggregate function SUM together with GROUP BY

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

What is the best way to execute this query in Active Record / Ruby on Rails

`SELECT sum(amount) as total_amount FROM payments GROUP BY person_id, product_id`

I can't seem to chain `sum` with `group` method. Do I have to resort to `find_by_sql` here?

Comment: `Payment.group("person_id, product_id").sum("amount")`. I think the sum method accepts a group_by option, but I'm not sure if I can use it with multiple column definition.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Something like:

```
Payment.group(:person_id).group(:product_id).sum(:amount)
```

should give you a hash whose keys are `[person_id, product_id]` arrays and whose values are the sums. You probably don't want to:

```
Payment.group('person_id, product_id').sum(:amount)
```

though, that might give you the right sums but the Hash's keys won't make much sense.

You can also say:

```
Payment.sum(:amount, :group => 'person_id, product_id')
```

but that will suffer the same brain damage in the keys as `Payment.group('person_id, product_id').sum(:amount)` does; however, an array for `:group`:

```
Payment.sum(:amount, :group => [ :person_id, :product_id ])
```

should produce the same Hash with Array keys as the double `.group` version. However, the `:group` form of `sum` is deprecated in Rails4 (thanks to [Ganeshwara Herawan Hananda Put](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1622847/ganeshwara-herawan-hananda-put) for noting this).

The above works fine in Rails3 and I see no reason that it wouldn't work in Rails4. I don't have a Rails4 setup handy so I can't verify that.

Comment: Saved me from hours of headache. I used the last one btw.

Comment: Seems that a tweak is needed in future version of ActiveRecord though: "DEPRECATION WARNING: Relation#calculate with finder options is deprecated"

Comment: What about `Payment.group(:person_id).group(:product_id).sum(:amount)`?

Comment: How to get the sum as integer only not as a hash of values when using group_by and sum?

Comment: @W.M. You'd pull the sum of the desired group out of the hash. If you only need the sum for one group then you don't want to GROUP BY at all, you'd want to use `where` to select just the group you want and then sum that.